# Radio button with label in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Hello everyone !**

> Today I'm trying to make a selectable attribute like [nike.com Air Force 1 product page to cart](https://www.nike.com/fr/t/chaussure-air-force-1-07-pour-3nGnlt/CJ0952-100)

> My problem is this:
> [image: Capture-d-cran-2020-10-19-12-57-35.png]

I want to select one item and store the value of the radio button in an state.

For that I'm using `useRef`:

```
const getValueFromRadio = React.useRef(null)
```

For call this references I'm using `onClick(myFunction)` on the label tag

```
<h1 className="text-center text-2xl">{product.name}</h1>
<div>
    <div className={'block my-3'}>
        {product.attribute !== undefined ? product.attribute.map((item, index) => <div className={'inline-block'} key={index}>
        <label onClick={labelOnclickHandler} className="cursor-pointer py-2 px-3 my-3 mx-2 border border-grey-500 hover:border-black h-3 rounded" htmlFor={item.id}>{item.value}</label>
        <input className="hidden" ref={getValueFromRadio} type="radio" id={item.id} value={item.value} name={'selectSize'}/>
              </div>)
         : null}
     </div>
</div>

// sorry for the piss of shit indentation.
```

If I have only one attribute reference will get the `S` size and the value that I store in my state is S:

```
const labelOnclickHandler = (e) => {
        const el = e.target.classList
        if (el.contains('border-grey-500')){ //toggling.
            el.remove('border-grey-500')
            el.add('border-black')
        } else {
            el.add('border-grey-500')
            el.remove('border-black')
        }
        setPrevElement(el) // get preview el for remove the border black.
        setSelectSize(getValueFromRadio.current.value) // state to cart.
}
```

But if I have multiple attribute, react or references return me every time "M", and i don't know if is a mistake or if is not the good way to make this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `htmlFor` on `<label>` and then, when you click this label you trigger the input if the `htmlFor` attribute is equal to the input `ID`.

Then you can handle the state change with the radioButton's **`onChange`** event:

```
<label htmlFor={item.id}>
   <input 
     id={item.id} 
     type='radio' 
     onChange={() => radioChangeHandler(item.id)}
   />
</label>
```

And then:

```
const radioChangeHandle = (id) => {
    setRadioState(id);
}
```

That way you could toggle your classes in a different way like this:

```
className={` ${ RadioState === item.id ? "border-black" : "border-grey-500" } cursor-pointer py-2 px-3`}
```

Comment: ok but with your code I have need a new functional component ? I don't think they will share the same state ?

Comment: But I'm trying this now I will comeback to you 

Answer (score 2):

Other solution is to pass the index of selected item:

```
  const labelOnclickHandler = (e, index) => {
    const el = e.target.classList
    if (el.contains('border-grey-500')){ //toggling.
        el.remove('border-grey-500')
        el.add('border-black')
    } else {
        el.add('border-grey-500')
        el.remove('border-black')
    }
    setPrevElement(el) // get preview el for remove the border black.
    setSelectSize(product.attribute[index].value) // state to cart.
}
```

And you don't need to use ref:

```
<div>
        <div className={"block my-3"}>
          {product.attribute !== undefined
            ? product.attribute.map((item, index) => (
                <div className={"inline-block"} key={index}>
                  <label
                    onClick={(e)=> labelOnclickHandler(e, index)}
                    className="cursor-pointer py-2 px-3 my-3 mx-2 border border-grey-500 hover:border-black h-3 rounded"
                    htmlFor={item.id}
                  >
                    {item.value}
                  </label>
                  <input
                    className="hidden"
                    type="radio"
                    id={item.id}
                    value={item.value}
                    name={"selectSize"}
                  />
                </div>
              ))
            : null}
        </div>
      </div>
```

I recommend you to avoid the use of index as key value (key={index}). More info here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Maybe you can use `` key={`product_attribute_${index}`} ``